# import logging.handlers breaks my program. Why?

Tags: python, python-import

While debugging a problem I have simplified the program in question to just few lines, but I still do not understand what's wrong. Could you please help?

```
import logging

def setup():
    logging.warning("start")
    import logging.handlers

setup()
```

The code above produces an exception:

> logging.warning("start")
>
> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'logging' referenced before assignment

and pylint complains:

> W:  5, 4: Redefining name 'logging' from outer scope (line 1)
>   (redefined-outer-name)

This modification seems to help, but I do not know why:

```
import logging.handlers as lh
```

Please note that the exception is thrown BEFORE the second import statement is executed. I'm confused.

Comment: This is one reason to put all your imports at global scope. Importing `logging.handlers` is not so expensive that you're going to improve your startup time by deferring it until `setup` is called.

Comment: You have the misconception that in python the scope is from the declration onwards, while this is not the case. Python has *block* scoping so in `def f():print(x); x= 1` **both** occurrences of `x` refer to the same *local* variable, and you get an error because you refer to the local before initializing it.

Comment: @chepner: `logging.handlers` is imported and used conditionally, i.e. only if a specific option is set. I have removed this and other unrelated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `logging.warning` function will try to reference the variable from local scope first in `setup()` function, which is from `import logging.handlers`, and it finds it to be declared after the line you're using it.

Try changing it to:

```
import logging

def setup():
    global logging
    logging.warning("start")
    import logging.handlers

setup()
```

Comment: `import` creates a *local* variable?! I did not expect that at all. But you are right, it's in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the problem if you disassemble the bytecode for that function:

```
>>> dis.dis(setup)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (logging)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (warning)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('start')
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             12 POP_TOP

  3          13 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             19 IMPORT_NAME              1 (logging.handlers)
             22 STORE_FAST               0 (logging)
             25 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             28 RETURN_VALUE
```

Note how the code imports the name `logging.handlers` and then **assigns** the module object to the name `logging`.

So basically it's like if your function were:

```
def setup():
    logging.warning('start')
    logging = __import__('logging.handlers')
```

Or, removing the import mechanism:

```
x = 0
def setup():
    # inside this function *all* x refer to the same object
    print(x)
    x = 1
```

Remember that a name in a given scope can only refer to one object. By having an assignment the compiler interprets `logging` as a *local* variable **for the whole scope, which is the complete function body** and thus the call to `warning` yields an `UnboundLocalError` because the assignment to `logging` is done afterwards.

You should either move the import as the first statement in the function or just move it in the global scope (which is the preferred way of doing it).

---

If you want to force the compiler to refer to the global variable you have to tell him so by adding a `global logging`/`global x` statement. In that case no local variable will be created but the global one will be used.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer. If I could, I would accept both.